# How to switch to the new Hotmail?

Tags: outlook.com, silverlight

I was recently informed that there was a new GUI for Hotmail that uses Silverlight.

How do I switch to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to recall reading that it is being rolled out incrementally. Users are receiving upgrades in groups, slowly at first, so the team can handle any issues that come up.

Ah, found the reference, had to check my history: [Update to the Hotmail rollout](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/06/29/update-to-the-hotmail-rollout.aspx)